# Python: Unable to kill process with keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, kill

I have a decorator written as such:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from functools import wraps
import sys
import os

def repeat_periodically(f):
    """ Repeat wrapped function every second """
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrap_helper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                threading.Timer(1.0, wrap_helper).start()
                f(self)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                try:
                    sys.exit(1)
                except:
                    os._exit(1)

        wrap_helper()

    return wrap
```

I'm not sure if it continues to open a new thread every single time it calls itself, but regardless, I'm unable to kill the process when I hit `CTRL + C`. I've also added the same `try-except` block in the function that I've decorated:

```
@repeat_periodically
def get_stats(self):
    try:
        # log some state information
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            sys.exit(1)
        except:
            os._exit(1)
```

My program just continues to run and all I see in the terminal is

```
^C <the stuff that I am logging>
<the stuff that I am logging>
<the stuff that I am logging>
```

In other words, it just keeps logging, even though I'm trying to kill it with `CTRL + C`.

**Update:**

I should mention that the above process is spun up from another thread:

```
tasks = [
    {'target': f, 'args': (arg1)},
    {'target': g},
]
for task in tasks:
    t = threading.Thread(**task)
    t.start()
```

Specifically it is the second task that spins up the Timer. However, if I set `t.daemon = True`, the process just runs once and exits. The first task uses [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog). I've essentially used the example code from the watchdog documentation:

```
def watch_for_event_file(Event):
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingCreateHandler(Event)
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

(Sorry for all the updates)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `daemon` attribute on your `Timer`?

Comment: Pretty sure barring `os._exit`, non-daemon threads will keep your program alive indefinitely. If your main thread gets the `KeyboardInterrupt` and doesn't explicitly `os._exit`, you're waiting on a bunch of `Timer` threads that: 1) Create new threads and 2) Aren't daemon threads. As an initial stab at fixing it, I'd recommend changing to `newtimer = threading.Timer(1.0, wrap_helper)`, `newtimer.daemon = True`, `newtimer.start()`, so your `Timer`s won't keep the process alive.

Comment: @JohnAnderson When I add `daemon=True` in `threading.Timer(daemon=True, ... )` I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'daemon'`

Comment: I think you will need to do something like `t = threading.Timer(1.0, wrap_helper)`, then `t.daemon = True`, then `t.start()`

Comment: @ShadowRanger No luck

Comment: @JohnAnderson No luck

Comment: Have you tried using `ctrl + d`?

Comment: @BinaryBuilder Doesn't work

Comment: So the problem now is that the `Thread` that starts the child threads is complete as soon as it starts target `g`. So it then exits, and the children (being daemons) get killed. If you want the child threads to continue, you will need to keep the parent thread running until you do the `CTRL + C`. Maybe put a sleep loop in it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson A sleep loop within `g`?

Comment: Yes, assuming `g` is in the thread that starts the `Timer` threads. That should keep the `g` thread running so that its daemon children will not get killed.

Comment: @JohnAnderson `g` is just `get_stats`. It's the decorator that's doing the repeating.

Answer (score 2):

From the Thread [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

`The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.`

So making your `Timer` threads as daemon threads should solve your problem. So replace:

```
threading.Timer(1.0, wrap_helper).start()
```

with:

```
t = threading.Timer(1.0, wrap_helper)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for Background Processes:
   a.Open Task Manager by pressing  `Ctrl +Shift+ Esc`
   b.Look for any lingering Python processes in the "Processes" or "Details" tab.
   c.If you find a Python process, right-click on it and choose "End Task."

After doing this open your cmd and hit CTRL+C again you would be able to kill the previous python process.